# Habilitar e desabilitar Ttimer

Tags: delphi

Como habilitar e desabilitar o `TTimer`? Tenho um `procedure`:

```
procedure TForm3.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
```

Quando clico em um botão de download, habilito o `Timer`:

```
Timer1.enabled := true;
```

E quando clico em cancelar ele deveria parar o `Timer`:

```
Timer1.enabled := False;
```

Mas não é isso que acontece. O `Timer` continua e fica processando os dados e exibindo em um Label...  para eu parar o Timer de vez tenho que usar:

```
Timer1.OnTimer :=  nil;
```

Qual a maneira correta de habilitar e desabilitar esse *timer*, pois na *procedure* `TForm3.Timer1Timer(` tem alguns comandos, e, mesmo eu dando `Timer1.enabled := False;` no botão cancelar ele continua processando e mostrando na tela.

Qual a maneira correta de usar o *timer* em uma situação dessa, habilitar e desabilitar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para desabilitar o *timer* basta digitar:

```
Timer1.enabled := False;
```

E para habilitar:

```
Timer1.enabled := True;
```

Você deve estar desabilitando o *timer* no lugar errado.

Comment: Realmente... eu estava desabilitando ele no local errado...  Estava dentro de um try ... Mas eu não sei se é errado, eu fui e coloquei uma variável global, onde recebia um valor booleano... daí verifico dentro do timer se é true ou False... deu super certo... daí eu não preciso desabilitar o timer...  Não sei se é vantagem...  mas dessa forma utilizo  apenas um timer com vários comandos diferentes... pois em nenhum momento ele será desabilitado...